# Шифрует ли SSH web-трафик при подключении к localhost в браузере?

Tags: linux, ssh, администрирование

У меня на сервере установлена панель для создания прокси. Она прослушивает по адресу 127.0.0.1 и работает на порте 2053. Через терминал ввожу: "sudo ssh -L 8080:localhost:2053 my_server_ip". В браузере ввожу: "localhost:8080". Затем ввожу данные для входа в панель и создаю конфигурации. **Данные при таком подключении передаются в открытом или шифрованном виде?**

Comment: Передаются между кем и кем? От вашего браузера к порту 8080 ssh-клиента — в открытом, от ssh-клиента к ssh-серверу — в шифрованном, от ssh-сервера к порту 2053 — опять в открытом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зашифрованном. Внутри зашифрованного соединения ssh создает два канала. Один для консоли, второй для порта